# Android login: Dynamic queries to retrieve data from MBO(SUP)

Tags: android, authentication, sup

I've searched around but cant seem to find the answer that could solve my problem.
Im trying to check that if the user login, it should check with the database & navigates to the next page if the username & pw matches in the database. I dont know where i went wrong because with the following codes below, im able to login even when the username & password doesnt match(Username wrong whereas password is correct), but if the password is wrong(username correct or wrong doesnt matters), the error message that i set shows up.
Is it because the password is the only one being read and username has already been overwrite? Im new to android & java, so please help. Thanks alot!

```
$   public void run()
                {
                    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {       

                            Query query = new Query();
                            query.select("x.username, x.password");
                            query.from("AccountLogin", "x");
                            AttributeTest ts = new AttributeTest();
                            ts.setOperator(AttributeTest.EQUAL);
                            ts.setAttribute("username");
                            ts.setValue(un.getText());
                            ts.setAttribute("password");
                            ts.setValue(pw.getText());
                            query.setTestCriteria(ts);



                            QueryResultSet qs = FinalDB.executeQuery(query);
                            if (!qs.isEmpty()) {

                                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(FinalActivity.this,    HomePage.class);
                                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                            } else {
                                error.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }


    }).start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this. check where condition or where query like this.

This code is only check password.

```
 Query query = new Query();
            query.select("x.username, x.password");
                                query.from("AccountLogin", "x");
            AttributeTest ts2 = new AttributeTest();
            ts2.setAttribute("x.password");

            ObjectList v = new ObjectList();
            v.add("password"); // use orignal password

            ts2.setValue(v);
            ts2.setOperator(AttributeTest.IN);
            query.where(ts2);

            query.setTake(take);
            query.setSkip(skip);

            lowIndex = skip;
            highIndex = lowIndex;

            if (!qs.isEmpty()) {

           Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(FinalActivity.this,    HomePage.class);
           startActivity(goToNextActivity);
           } else {
           error.setText("Login failed. Username and/or password doesn't match.");
            }
```